# Shortest Paths Graph Too Big

Tags: algorithm, memory, shortest-path, dijkstra

There are 2 humans that face a certain direction (up, left, down or right). They can turn clockwise, counterclockwise and move one spot forward. Both humans are on a board with obstacles. They both have a certain position, expressed in coordinates `(x,y)`, and an amount of energy. Moving and turning requires a certain amount of energy : `ENERGY_MOVE` and `ENERGY_TURN`.

The goal is to move these 2 humans as close as possible to each other, expressed as manhattan distance. The manhattan distance does not look at obstacles (so it's really just a matter of bringing the humans as close as possible to each other while using the least amount of energy possible). The solution should be optimal.

I've figured out Dijkstra could take care of this, but there is one issue. Java arrays have an integer index so I can't store all the vertices. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why can't you store 4,000 * 4,000 = 16,000,000 vertices in an array? Java ints are signed and 32 bit, so you can get up to 2 billion items in an array.

Comment: @delnan I think it might be a memory issue, and if that's the case then yes, he should be able to increase some max-parameters and go with the array as originally intended.

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) store the entire array, you might Google around for a Java implementation for sparse arrays or sparse matrices.

Comment: I don't get the memory issue. The array should take ~64 MB. Certainly something a java program can handle. Can you post the code that results in memory outage?

Comment: The [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is vaguely similar to Dijkstra's but can be much faster.

Comment: The thing is, while technically the board can be up to 4000x4000 its size has a width and height of maximum Long.MAX_VALUE, so I shouldn't have written that. The A* algorithm won't be optimal I believe...

Comment: How can a board be "up to 4000x4000" and at the same time have a width of height of `LONG_MAX`?  That makes no sense.  Also: I can't imagine a situation where A* is slower than Dijkstras, and they both return the shortest paths.

Comment: In the game itself it's probably gonna keep being in the 4000x4000 range, but technically I shouldn't assume it. A* won't always work well enough when the energy of the human is not sufficient. It is not optimal in this case, though, yes, it will be faster.

Comment: Did you use Dijkstra for this? It seems to me there are some situations where it would not produce correct results/require significant expansion of the graph due to the turning cost. When Dijkstra settles a node, you'd have to take into account the direction it is facing. You could end up with underestimated costs